# Angular4 app, npm install gives '$ is not recognized as an internal or external command' error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have an Angular 4 application that uses a package called 'ngular2-google-map-auto-complete', https://github.com/rajan-g/angular2-google-place-autocomplete

It has worked previously but I am picking up the code base after some months off it.

My problme is tht when I am running 'npm install' I am getting the below console error...

```
angular2-google-map-auto-complete@2.0.7 postinstall C...\node_modules\angular2-google-map-a
uto-complete
$(npm bin)/typings install
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I suspect this is to do with the installed typings but am not sure what to do to fix it.
Does anyone have any ideas?

My packages file looks like this...

```
{
"name": "tilecase",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "TileCase",
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --content-base src/",
"test": "karma start",
"build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "git://github.com/bencameron00/TileCase.V2.UI.git"
},
"license": "UNLICENSED",
"dependencies": {
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^4.3.6",
"": "^3.26.1",
"": "^3.2.12",
"angular2-google-map-auto-complete": "^2.0.7",
"angular2-google-maps": "^0.15.0",
"angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.2.9",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.1.28",
"angular2-moment": "^0.8.2",
"angulartics2": "^1.6.3",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.26.0",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"karma-webpack": "^1.8.1",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.2.6",
"ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.2.0",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.0",
"ng2-img-cropper": "^0.7.7",
"ng2-page-scroll": "^3.2.3",
"ng2-social-share": "^0.0.10",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
"rxjs": "^5.0.3",
"signalr": "^2.2.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"": "^3.25.37",
"": "^3.2.12",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.1.24",
"css-loader": "^0.23.1",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.8.5",
"html-loader": "^0.4.3",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"karma": "^0.13.22",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
"ng2-facebook-sdk": "^1.1.0",
"node-sass": "^3.8.0",
"null-loader": "^0.1.1",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"rimraf": "^2.5.2",
"sass-loader": "^3.2.1",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
"typescript": "^2.2 ",
"typings": "^2.1.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.0",
"webpack-svgstore-plugin": "^3.0.0"
}
}
```

Comment: typings have been [deprecated](https://github.com/typings/typings#deprecation-notice-regarding-typescript20), you would need to update your package.json. Cheers!!

Comment: Ok cool, what updates do I need to make for example?

Comment: you should look into your typings.json file, what dependencies you have there, and based upon that you can see if there are corresponding type def files available and then add as dev dependencies, detailed instruction on how to serach is available in the link i added in last comment, Cheers!!

Comment: Could it be because you've used "$" as part of the command? it happens when you copy and paste a command from a reference online. like "$(node bin)/npm install" which means it's a command but $ is only an indication and not part of your command.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I found this issue only for Windows machine. Mac and Linux are working fine.